# What issues can arise when you call a function within a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in the process of learning coding and below we have a simple conversion between Fahrenheit and Celsius. I have created a loop in the check function that will call the convert function again if the user inputs something in the confirm array (I removed the arrays to save space).

From what I've been told it is better coding practice to have something like a do-while loop as opposed to calling functions within functions.

So I'm wondering what issues could arise with functions within functions that new people may not think of.

```
def convert():

    while True:
        usrchoice = input("Would you like to change Cel or Far? :")
        if usrchoice in Celsius:
            usrcel = int(input("Input temp in Celc: "))
            far = usrcel * (9.0/5.0) +32
            print("that's " + str(far) + " degrees in Far")   
            break
        elif usrchoice in Far:
            usrfar = int(input("Input temp in Far: "))
            cel = (usrfar - 32) / (9.0/5.0)
            print("that's " + str(cel) + " degrees in Cel" )
            break
        else: print("Choose Cel or Far")
        continue



def check():

    while True:
        dblchk = input("Would you like to make another conversion? ")
        if dblchk in Confirm:
            convert()                                                           
        elif dblchk in Deny:
            print("Conversion finished")
            break
        else: print("Please enter yes or no")
        continue


convert()

check()
```

Comment: hint: it's the name of this site

Comment: "From what I've been told it is better coding practice to have something like a do-while loop as opposed to calling functions within functions." Can you clarify what you mean by this? In general, there's absolutely nothing wrong with calling a function inside a function.

Comment: Just a note that Python doesn't really have DO-WHILE loops, though of course you can fake it. In Python it is considered totally normal/acceptable to have recursive function calls. But you do have to be careful.

Comment: Calling functions within other functions is a completely normal and expected thing to do. Almost every program will involve doing that.

Comment: There are certainly plenty of ways to do it wrong. For example, newcomers trying to write a "retry" thing or one of those ubiquitous text adventure projects often end up thinking of function calls as "this thing is what's supposed to happen next", which tends to lead to stack overflow problems or forgetting about what's going to happen when the function returns.

Comment: @Chris I interpreted the OP to mean "what is wrong with recursing every time the user wants to do another conversion, rather than looping?", with which there clearly is something wrong.

Comment: @chris I'm mostly self taught, but I have a saintly boos that is helping me learn coding. I was told by him to do that when possible. Maybe it was to help me learn the process. Sort of like "measure twice, cut once". It was probably to help me avoid stack overflows and the such. Thanks for the help everyone, trying to understand the coding process better.

Comment: @Phydeaux, we shouldn't have to guess what the question is about. In my opinion this question should be closed as "unclear what you're asking" unless OP makes an [edit] to clarify the question. "Don't call functions from other functions" is very clearly bad advice. "Don't call a function from _itself_" at least hints at something useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you may get a stack overflow!

When you call a new function, some information about it is saved in memory. While it runs, its local variables are saved there as well. This structure is called a "stack frame". When you call a function within a function, the stack frames that describe the caller stay there since control must (or at least is expected to) return to the caller at some point (there are techniques like tail-call optimisation to prevent that, but they don't apply to most cases), so the deeper you go into recursion, the more stack frames are pushed onto the stack.

It may happen that you'll run out of memory solely because of the excessive amount of stack frames on the stack, which is known as a stack overflow, which causes your program to crash.

As an example, I once wrote a recursive function that kept crashing my Python interpreter because it was running in an environment which was very low on memory. Once I removed *one* single local variable from said function, it stopped crashing. As you can see, sometimes one local variable (that's copied over and over again in new stack frames) can make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm trying to go from the point of just making things works to properly understanding why they work. So two secondary question to this;
    In a do-while/do-until loop, does each loop create a new function/new stack frame, or would it be the same 'instance'?
   And secondly, as long as there are proper ways for the code to avoid unwanted recursion and exit, there isn't much concern with stack overflow correct?

Comment: @MarsHall 1) loops are different from recursion. Loops don’t create stack frames, they just jump back and forth (from the end of the loop to the condition check and back). 2) Of course, as long as one writes code “properly”, there’s little chance of stack overflows/segmentation faults and stuff like this. The problem is, it’s not so easy to write “proper” code, so one should keep an eye out for potential infinite recursion when dealing with recursive functions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know it's a basic question and all, just trying to understand the rules of coding a bit better and this definitely helps.